# Regex to replace first and last spaces in html tags

Tags: php, regex

I have text with html tags inside. I need to replace only one or more spaces after opening tag and before closing tag, **but not replace anything else**

For example if i have:

```
la la la <h1>   text text </h1> bla bla bla <b> text </b>
```

It would become:

```
la la la <h1>text text</h1> bla bla bla <b>text</b>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would be to show what you have tried and where your code is failing

Comment: You may want to use an HTML parser here.

Comment: Apart from the comments above: You probably will not notice any difference when a browser renders the html. Probably, there are exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/(<[^\/]*?>)\s*|\s*(<\/.*?>)/';
$str = 'la la la <h1>   text text </h1> bla bla bla <b> text </b>';
$substitution = '$1$2';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $substitution, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

This will give you `The result of the substitution is la la la <h1>text text</h1> bla bla bla <b>text</b>`

This pattern will work with any whitespace. Also whitespace is optional like in the second example here:

https://regex101.com/r/9DFVIw/1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've updated regex a little bit so it could match one or more spaces, not zero or more:                                                                              '/(<[^\/]*?>)\s{1,}|\s{1,}(<\/.*?>)/'

Comment: Then I would suggest to use this instead: `(<[^\/]*?>)\s+|\s+(<\/.*?>)`. The plus sign is a shorthand for {1,} and might be faster to read and understand. At least when you are familiar with regex ;)

Comment: @Eydamos How do i add "&nbsp" in the first and last instead of removing spaces from first and last? I tried adding nbsp as substitution, but it removes the tags

Comment: @Shiraaz just use `$1&nbsp;$2` as the substitution. With the example code above this would generate `The result of the substitution is la la la <h1>&nbsp;text text&nbsp;</h1> bla bla bla <b>&nbsp;text&nbsp;</b>`

Answer (score 0):

**Regex might not be the best tool** for what you are trying to achieve, if you do really want to have a regex solution:

```
(?<=>) +([^<]*) +(?=<\/)
```

and replace the matches with the backreference `\1` in order to trim it.

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/MN6juN/3/

You could also use this regex that is more restrictive:

```
<([^>]*)> +([^<]*) +<\/\1>
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/MN6juN/4

and replace the matches with the backreference `\2` in order to trim it.

Otherwise, go for a HTML parser solution.